# HTML email multiple cid references do not show on hotmail

Tags: html, image, email

I am constructing an html email message with images embedded as cid attached references and it all looks good in most of the email viewers apart from hotmail. There, if I have two images that are referenced with the same cid in the src, I don't see the second image.
Does anyone know what this could be about?

Thank you

Comment: Source code please. We can't really help you by guessing.

Comment: It will be a bit complicated, I am using a custom java library for MSExchange. I was hoping that someone has the same issue with hotmail and know how to fix it. Thank you

Comment: Can we at least see the outputted HTML?
Also you might want to add the java tag.

Why don't you try using hosted imagery rather than attached ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I ran into this once. The rather hacky solution I came up with was simply to attach the same image twice, with different cids. Solved the problem. If that works for you - great! If it doesn't, I look forward to hearing a better solution.

Comment: Somewhere I think I saw one of the specs say that's the right way to attach the same image twice in the message inefficient though it may be

Comment: Thanks for that @JessicaBrown. At the time I found no other means of achieving this, but have a hard time believing this is really what it comes to. If you or anyone else reading this comes across that documentation, and feels like adding a link, I would be interested in seeing it. (And it would add legitimacy to my hacky looking solution.)